# CE_CLASS_ENVY Method excessively uses methods of another class Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spotbugs

Spotbug is giving the violation for the below code

```
 @SpringBootTest
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    class LocationServiceTest {
    
    @MockBean
    LocationService locationService;
    
    @Test 
    void shouldFetchAllLocation_whenQueried() {
       when(locationService.findAll(any(),any()).thenReturn(List.of(location("LOC1"), location("LOC2"))
    }
    
   private Location location(String id) {
        return Location.builder()
               .id(id)
               .name("name"+id)
               .postalAddress("PostalAddress")
               .region("region")
               .build();       
}
    }
```

This method(location) makes extensive use of methods from another class over methods of its own, but the method location(String id) calling in the same class only not in any other Test class but still gives this spotbug violation .

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Maybe exclude tests from this check? Of course a unit test access the class under test.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
return Location.builder()
               .id(id)
               .name("name"+id)
               .postalAddress("PostalAddress")
               .region("region")
               .build();
```

Do this

```
return new Location(id, "name"+id, "PostalAddress","region");
```

- of course, you should have a matching constructor in the Location class.

It will fix the **CE_CLASS_ENVY** FindBugs issue